# how to use groupby function in the following scenario?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am a beginner in python. Just started learning it online.
I have a dataset of uber trips with below columns,
START_DATE  END_DATE    CATEGORY    START   STOP    MILES   PURPOSE

I need to find the most frequent route taken using groupby function. **(Route= combination of START & END points)**. I used the following code from google and got an output. But I am not sure how it worked.

```
df.groupby(['START','STOP']).START.value_counts()
```

Can anyone suggest the most efficient way to use the groupby function here?

Comment: what's your column name

Answer (score 0):

Use groupby() function to form groups based on more than one category

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(['START','STOP'])
```

If we have two columns `start` and `stop` in your dataframe then it first group by `start` column then it group inside the start group by `stop` column

```
grouped_df['START'].value_counts()
```